# CVS: Checkout single file from list of branches

Tags: bash, shell, cvs

I have the task to checkout a single file from a list of around 300 branches.
The filename and path is the  same on every branch.

Is there a cvs command to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
for branch in $branches
do
    cvs checkout -p -r $branch </path/to/file> > $branch/<file>
done
```

The `-p` option checks out to standard output. You can then redirect to a filename of your choice.

Comment: Hmm, actually I've done this with `cvs update` before, but not `cvs checkout`. I assume it'll work with `checkout`, otherwise, you can just get an initial workspace and update on the one file.